# Is Linux Mint's version of Firefox really Free software? Is it compliant with the MPL?

Tags: mpl, free-software-definition

Trying to keep this as short as possible... In a VM, to test a problem of someone else, I installed a fresh Linux Mint 17.3 and opened Firefox. The search bar (right of the address bar) didn't include Google as an option, as I'm used to. Proceeding to the option to add search providers, I finally found it, along with a "reason" it wasn't there by default.

[image]

A little put off by that, but not too worried about it, (they need money too, right?) I found the link for Google and enabled it. Now it was available, and all was good. Except that it wasn't.

Normally, as I type in the search box I get suggestions that lend themselves to what's been typed so far. Often this shortens my typing significantly. Now, it wasn't doing that. I switched back to Yahoo, and it work as normal. Back to Google, no such luck. Not unfamiliar with `about:config` I poked around, then dug around, and did some comparisons with settings between Yahoo and Google. No dice, can't find what triggers the difference in behavior.

"Ok," says I to self, I'm just go to the repository and drop the Mint custom version, and install the Mozilla original version. Into software manager and drill down to Firefox. No options to upgrade, downgrade, switch versions, or anything else, just "Remove" which, after doing that, only gives the option to "Install." Shows what version will be installed, but no options to change it.

I'm not a Mint user, so I don't know if there's other options for controlling software or not. I'm sure that a source install is likely to be available somehow. But.. Is that the point.

As I understand "Free" software, it's about choice, and not having someone, disto author in this case, dictate what I can use. The option to add Google seemed to fulfill that promise, until I found it only half-worked. Making it difficult, maybe prohibitively so, to replace the restrictive version with an unrestricted version was the icing on the cake.

## Edit

<strike>So, Linux Mint, Linux kernel and all, is, or is not, Free software? BTW: The source is available, so it's probably "Open source" at least.</strike>

The proper question relates only to the version of Firefox, firefox_51.0.1+linuxmint1+rosa, supplied in the repos of Mint, not to the distro itself, or to any other package in the disto, including the kernel. As such, the question should have been, "Does the version of Firefox supplied with Linux Mint 17.3 comply with the MPL and is it still free within the FSF concept?"

**Notes:**

In re: the "crippling" of the software: I don't know how long I've been using Mozilla products, or Firefox in general, but as their product have evolved, and as I've moved from one distro to another, between OSs, and between platforms, I have become accustomed to features behaving consistently across them all.

I'll not argue, here or in comments, as to whether or not that version is "crippled." I do know that it **is** modified, and that it does not work the same as every other release of Firefox that I have available to me for testing. The modified source code is available, to anyone who wants it, and according to the accepted answer, modified or not it does comply with the FSF's four freedoms. That was the question, and that is the answer.

I have been replying to comments that go beyond the scope of the question, and I probably shouldn't have been. By my rep, even across SE as a whole, you can see that I'm learning the Stack Exchange way. Comments about the real question will be replied to, while my crippled phrase, my improper scope to include the distro, and related debates won't be fueled by me. Further insights, or explanations that are germane to the OS topic are welcomed and encouraged. That's how others like me can learn.

Comment: There used to be similar issues with firefox on Ubuntu -- installing the stock version of firefox (I can't find a better link but it's mentioned in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/759610/178354)) might help with the practical issue in paragraph 4.

Comment: linux is free. you have the freedom to choose another distro, which configures firefox the way you want it to be. firefox is free, download the source and compile it on mint. if you freely choose to use a distro and choose to use the distros paketmanager, you have to live with the pre-desicions. you are free to compile your linux from scratch... maybe you have enough time... :)

Comment: Mozilla might be able to prevent the distribution from changing Firefox in such a way, as long as it's called Firefox in the distribution using its trademark rights.

Comment: You may be confused what "repository" means. In the case of Linux distribution, it is the particular collection of all software that belongs to the specific distro. Nothing else. So you cannot use the repository tools to install software from outside it. And the Mozilla hosted version is not in it; that's all. That doesn't mean it's less free; quite the contrary: there are non-free programs in the repository itself.

Comment: *Free* can mean a lot of things, and it can mean different things to different people. This is a general property of words. What sort of answer to this question would be useful to you? Can you make it more specific?

Comment: @reinierpost The sort of answer I was looking for is like what unor provided below. The _Free_ in question here was relative to FSF, inline with the topic of this site. I'm waiting, unexpectantly, for a better answer. Don't want to instantly accept, though I almost did since I can't imagine a better answer. 13 upvotes in 3 hours pretty much says others agree.

Comment: @MrLister Not confused by "repository" only spoiled by the one I use. In openSUSE, for most things that they have customized they also provide an "upstream," or unbranded, version in the repos. May not be the norm, since I've not yet experimented with other distros. Once I have a modern computer, that is on my bucket list. Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that this feature has been deliberately 'crippled'. Adding a search engine in the ordinary way doesn't tell Firefox anything about how to ask for search suggestions. Did you try the instructions available online for fixing this issue by editing an XML file?

Comment: @random832 Yes, I do think it was deliberately crippled. Provide a link to the XML file instructions and I'll experiment later. Assuming it works won't show it wasn't crippled, however. Removing something that's included in the base version _is_ deliberate.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver What I was saying is that it sounds like you are suggesting that they deliberately sabotaged it so that adding google in the way you added it would not enable suggestions - which would go far beyond simply deciding to remove google, whereas the reality is that what you added was never the same thing that they removed.

Comment: Note that under **Options > Search** there are checkboxes for search suggestions (for the search box and the URL box separately).

Comment: See the page about [Firefox support for OpenSearch XML files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox).

Comment: I don't understand what would make you think that you having difficulty installing a search engine means the entire operating system is not free.

Comment: @curiousdannii Check out my first comment to unor's answer. In the question I should have been _much_ narrower in my focus and referred only to the version of Firefox that comes with Mint, not the OS as a whole. It was in reaction to a crippling of a package by a distro, coupled with their wanting payment from search providers to be included, that got me rolling. I've been lucky in the past, and sometimes take freedom for granted to easily, and assume it will always _be_ there. Creating an inconvenience is not the same as removing a freedom, though it felt that way at the time.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver There's zero evidence that anything was crippled. It's ridiculous to call conspiracy when manually installing something is difficult.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver - I'm with curiousdanni on this. There is no evidence that there was any "crippling". There is no evidence that your failure to get the behaviour you wanted was due to any deliberate action on anybody's part. They chose not to include it in the distro. End of story. If something about Google search was inconvenient, you should be wondering why Google let you down, and didn't make sure their add-on was easy to configure the way you wanted. I see no rational basis for being upset with Linux Mint. You just wish their priorities matched yours.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Your question is too vague because it doesn't make it clear what you mean to ask. On one hand you ask whether Mint complies with a particular free software license, on the other you complain about a particular behaviour in Firefox - I just don't see the connection.

Comment: @reinierpost As stated in below the __Edit__ line, the question and the behavior are linked. Is the change in functionality of Firefox in line with the license. As unor so clearly explained, it _is_. In line with the 4 freedoms of the FSF, what was done didn't violate the license. My adjustments to their adjustments also does not violate the license, under the same 4 freedoms. If you feel that there is a better way to restate the corrected part of the question, please edit it. Perhaps reading unor's  excellent answer, and my comments after to 2/25 edits will help in that.

Comment: Now in Linux Mint 20.2 enabling Google search engine remained complex, however I do see search suggestions how when it is added. If somebody understood source code of modified Firefox, please explain how disabling google engine was done, I'm interested, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Software is *free* (as [defined by the FSF](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html.en)) if it gives you the four freedoms:

> - The freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose (freedom 0).
> - The freedom to study how the program works, and change it so it does your computing as you wish (freedom 1). Access to the source code is a precondition for this.
> - The freedom to redistribute copies so you can help your neighbor (freedom 2).
> - The freedom to distribute copies of your modified versions to others (freedom 3). By doing this you can give the whole community a chance to benefit from your changes. Access to the source code is a precondition for this.

It could have bad usability, it could have bugs, it could spy on you, it could technically restrict browsing to certain sites or installation of certain software, it could intentionally delete your music – as long as it gives you the four freedoms, it qualifies as *free software*.

Thanks to these freedoms, you are allowed and enabled to change the things you don’t like, and to share the changed software with others. Note that this doesn’t mean that you need to be able to change it e.g. within the GUI, or that is has to be easy – it just has to be allowed (legally) and possible (source code provided).

---

So the issue you mention doesn’t affect whether or not Linux Mint is free software.

Is it free software? Well, this depends on what is meant with "it", as a GNU/Linux distribution consists of many different parts, and could come with separate but pre-installed software.
If we talk about the ISO that can be downloaded (so not taking any packages into account that can be installed from their repository): According to [Linux Mint’s FAQ *Does Linux Mint include proprietary drivers?*](https://www.linuxmint.com/faq.php), it doesn’t contain any proprietary software (but note that this applies to the current release; it seems that this was not the case for older releases). So yes, Linux Mint is free software.

Comment: Fair enough. Crippling it "feels" wrong, but per the four freedoms, it's allowed. Their mods are covered by freedom 1, I guess. +1 for the extra re Mint as a whole, when I should have narrowed the Q to their mod'ed Firefox.

Comment: Agreed, but you are "free" to uncripple it ;-)

Comment: Also, a lot of users want to have search-as-you-type disabled either for privacy reasons or to avoid paying for extra network traffic. The distributor made a default choice that is likely to be more aligned with their user base rather than force someone else's personal preference on them.

Comment: @SimonRichter In Firefox, standard anyway, if privacy is set, then auto suggest in the URL bar is turned off automatically. It can also be disable merely for convenience with privacy turned off, if it's annoying to the user. My surprise was that it worked for their preferred search engines but not for the ones they shunned.

Comment: Related: [Free as in “free speech”, not as in “free beer”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/2516/571) on [ell.se]. Full disclosure: The accepted answer is my own (but there are several others as well).

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver - Perhaps they didn't "cripple" Google. I hope it is obvious that "they" are free to include it or not - otherwise, they do not have freedom. Equally, they aren't obligated to do unpaid work to make sure it works conveniently. I think the only possible moral/freedom objection you could have, would be if you or Google or someone else figures out how to make it entirely painless to do the install you tried to do, and get the configuration to be exactly the way you wanted, and they somehow actively interfered with you making that add-on available.

Comment: On the other hand, if software that includes components that are primarily for the purpose of surveilling you, a chilling effect could be argued to be preventing you from enjoying those freedoms (IANAL)...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:

> *Software*: refer to the non-physical part of the computer system in the form of encoded information that controls its
> behavior. A collection of computer programs, libraries and related data.
>
> *Computer program* is a collection of instructions that performs a specific task when executed by a computer.
>
> *Source code* is any collection of computer instructions, possibly with comments, written using a human-readable programming language,
> usually as ordinary text.

Users actually read the *source code* to understand the *program* that runs in their computers and is distributed to them in form of *software* (with data, config files, documentation, etc...)

The users can know the *program* (what the computer does) by reading the documentation or trying the features but they can not understand the encoded information that the machine actually runs (are just numbers) therefore they can not modify the program directly.

When a user read the the *FSF definition of free software* he might be tempted to feel like anything can be made with the software but it is not.

The program is a pre-established sequence of instructions by the *programmers* who make it. In the precise moment that you modify the sequence of instruction you are creating another *program*. (one new version is actually another program with the same name)

So even when they say...

> The freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose (freedom
> 0).

the user has a limited degree of freedom. The program would never give you the freedom to do something it was not designed to do. Nevertheless, the user has a certain pre-designed amount of options to drive its behavior through configuration parameters.

Now that we are clear that you are actually using *another version* of firefox. Can they distribute it?

> The freedom to distribute copies of your modified versions to others
> (freedom 3). By doing this you can give the whole community a chance
> to benefit from your changes. Access to the source code is a
> precondition for this.

That makes clear that they have the right to modify Firefox and distribute it. What is not clear is whether they can use the same name or Artwork for the software, given the precedence that Debian seems to be forced to use different ones in their fork named **Iceweasel**.

You will find more if you put this into your firefox's URL address bar:

```
about:rights
```

Important here is the [Mozilla Public License](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/). It is GPL compatible (in the sense that is not contradictory), but it allows that some parts of the software are not **GPL** if it is properly remarked. Check the sections:

- 1.12. “Secondary License”
- 1.5. “Incompatible With Secondary Licenses”
- 3.3. Distribution of a Larger Work
- 10.4. Distributing Source Code Form that is Incompatible With Secondary Licenses
- Exhibit B - “Incompatible With Secondary Licenses” Notice

So the way to check this is:

1. Locate the source code of the version.
2. Check the **Exhibit B** of the license there. Otherwise not stated there the GPL also applies.

According to the [GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) under the section: *Conveying Modified Source Versions* you will see:

> a) The work must carry prominent notices stating that you modified it,
> and giving a relevant date.

and that seems to be precisely the notification that your screenshot shows.

So I think that **yes**, is **free software**, at less you locate the **MPL** license accompanying the source code with their modifications and note it states the contrary.